# Using rPython import numpy with python 3.5

Tags: numpy, rpython

My R version is 3.4.1, python version is 3.5.2 , and OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2

I have set RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 when installing rPython, which is my default python version for rPython.

```
♥ python.exec('import sys')
♥ python.exec('print(sys.version)')
3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

When I import numpy through rPython (there is no issue with using import numpy in python 3.5, everything works fine.), I got this:

```
♥ python.exec('import numpy')
Error in python.exec("import numpy") :
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyType_GenericNew
```

However, if I set RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=2 and reinstall rPython, the import numpy works. How can I successfully import numpy under rPython with python 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, can you import any packages into python 3.5.3 from R/rPython?

I am also having this problem. The error I get is exactly the same as the posters (numpy won't load). I later found that I cannot import any packages.  I can however import packages in python 2.7.13 and python 3.5.3 (just not through R/rPython).  This leads me to believe that this is an 'rPython' R package error.  Here are the things that I have tried to do to fix this:

1) I have tried installing/reinstalling the R package rPython to use either python 2.7.13 or python 3.5.3.  I could connect R to python 2.7.13 via reinstall of the rPython package:

```
install.packages("rPython",lib= "home/myusername/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4", configure.vars= "RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=2")
```

Using "RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3" during install similarly allowed me to connect R with python 3.5.3.  I could call "import numpy" from R when rPython was connected to python 2.7.13, but not when connected with 3.5.3.

2) I have tracked down all numpy and scipy's which had been previously installed and uninstalled them.  I had several copies of each for both python 2.7.13 and python 3.5.3.  Reinstalling using pip and pip3 did not fix the problem (I restarted R beforehand to be safe).

From both accounts this seems to be a problem with the R package 'rPython'.  You could try the newer 'reticulate' package from R, and see if this works better for you.  However, I have not been able to get parallel threads to work when using reticulate to connect R with python, and this is unfortunately what I need to do.  Threading did however work perfectly when using 'rPython', but the package I need requires python 3+. I will keep troubleshooting and update this post if I am able to solve it. In the meantime, give 'reticulate' a shot, it is a very neat package.

**EDIT**
I was able to load numpy from python 3.5.3 in R using the 'reticulate' package.

**EDIT2** For those who find this post in the future, the only solution I could find to use python3 code with multithreading from R was to call python files with system(python3 "path_to_python_script" arg1 arg2 arg3)

Comment: Thanks Bartimus, I have tried reticulate (it is developed by Rstudio guys and reticulated python is the longest snake in the world lol) and it can import numpy with python 3.5.  And answer your question, yes, I can import some other packages, e.g., pymongo, datetime, and bson, except numpy under rPython with python 3.5.The only thing I care is integrating python3 in R, so you really help me with this, thanks again.